# iCarousel not showing images from Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimage, icarousel

I am using iCarousel with my app to show cards from Parse

I have the following code, but it always crash with the following message

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b07590'
```

I tried the same structure with collection view and it works fine but I can't integrate iCarousol to the code

Can any one help me, what is missed

the code is

```
    @implementation carousolViewController

@synthesize cardData, cardFileArray,carousel, items;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //set up data
    //your carousel should always be driven by an array of
    //data of some kind - don't store data in your item views
    //or the recycling mechanism will destroy your data once
    //your item views move off-screen
    self.cardFileArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        [cardFileArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //it's a good idea to set these to nil here to avoid
    //sending messages to a deallocated viewcontroller
    carousel.delegate = nil;
    carousel.dataSource = nil;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.title = cardData.themeNames;

    carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;

    [self queryParseMethod];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    //free up memory by releasing subviews
    self.carousel = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)queryParseMethod {

    if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Birthday Cards"]) {

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:WALL_OBJECT3];
        if (cardFileArray == 0) {
            query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

        }

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                cardFileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
                [iCarousel load];
            }
        }];

    } else if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Love Cards"]) {

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:WALL_OBJECT2];
        if (cardFileArray == 0) {
            query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

        }

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                cardFileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
                [iCarousel load];
            }
        }];

    } else if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Islamic Cards"]) {

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:WALL_OBJECT];
        if (cardFileArray == 0) {
            query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

        }

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                cardFileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
                [iCarousel load];
            }
        }];

    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //return the total number of items in the carousel
    return [cardFileArray count];
}


- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

       if (view == nil)
    {

        view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300.0f, 300.0f)] autorelease];
    }


       PFObject *imageObject = [cardFileArray objectAtIndex:index];
       PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:KEY_IMAGE4];


     [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
          if (!error) {

               ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;



            }




       }];




  return view;
}



@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You must implement these methods:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view;
```

and:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel;
```